# Weblogic server: get all settings

Tags: weblogic, settings, command-line-interface

I am looking for a command-line script which can give me an overview of all settings which are set in Weblogic server. For Glassfish the following command exists asadmin get '*'.

Anybody an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a scripting framework for WebLogic called [WLST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/using_WLST.html) that can assist you with this.